# Populate for loop with user input with JSON

Tags: python, json, api

I am still new to Python and I am still trying a lot of new things in this aspect. I am working with an API that contains JSON data that looks as follow:

```
products: [
{
id: 66057248,
createdAt: "2018-02-28T14:55:22+01:00",
updatedAt: "2018-04-26T20:44:12+02:00",
isVisible: true,
visibility: "visible",
hasMatrix: false,
data01: "",
data02: "",
data03: "",
url: "product-name",
title: "product name",
fulltitle: "product name",
    etc...
```

What I am trying to do now is to let the user give input on the values in the JSON file that he wants to compare with each other. I tried a couple of things but so far without a result. I am probably doing something stupid, but I don't know what.

As you can see in my code below, I ask the user two times for the input, and these values are the values that I want to add to the for loop below. My question now is, what am I doing wrong and how can I insert the input data in the `for` loop?

```
import requests
import json

response = requests.get('http://inserturlhere.com')

data =response.text
parsed=json.loads(data)

first_value = input ('Name of first value: ')
second_value = input ('Name of second value: ')

first_test = ['first_value']
second_test = ['second_value']

for product in parsed['products']:
    if product[first_test] == product[second_test] :
        print(product['id'])
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? The json snippet is incomplete, `requests.get('APIURL')` won't run, and we don't know what `parse['orders']` refers to.

Comment: This is largely a guess as to your intentions due to lack of context, but when you write 'first_test' = ['first_value'], that's not doing anything with the var in first_value.

Comment: @jpp Did some adjustments to my post, the code is working if I use the param  anyway let's say in the first input 'first_value' I fill in 'title' and in the second one 'full_title' . I want that in the loop both of these values will be compared with each other. 

This is only working if my for loop looks like this:

for product in parsed['orders']:
    if product['title'] == product['full_title'] :
        print(product['id'])

But as you can see this is static, I want to make it dynamic to let the user decide which values he wants to compare.

Comment: @Solaiman, Still confused, What is `parsed['orders']`? [can you print an example] The first and only time `orders` comes up is in the 3rd last line.

Comment: Also back to @AriK's question: what is the point of `first_test` and `second_test` here?  Indexing into the `product` dictionary using a list with a single string (e.g., `['first_value']`) seems unlikely to be your actual intention

Comment: @jpp My mistake, I have changed it now. This is how it should be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what the purpose of `first_test` and `second_test` would be in your code. But could this be what you are trying to do?

```
import requests

response = requests.get('http://inserturlhere.com')
products = response.json()['products']

first_value = input('Name of first value: ')
second_value = input('Name of second value: ')

for product in products:
    if product[first_value] == product[second_value]:
        print(product['id'])
```

Note that any misspelling in the user inputs for first_value or second_value will result in a KeyError, so you should probably include som error handling with try-except.

Comment: I tried the code above but I get a key error anyway even when I fill in everything right. That's why I tried to work with first_test and second_test to convert both inputs to the same format as 

 print(product['id']) 

In the hope that it would work then

Comment: If you get a key error, then clearly you have not filled out valid key names. What exactly is the keyerror you get?

Comment: Ugh, I feel so stupid now. I was so close actually if I look at my first code. You are right your solutions works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Below are a couple of solutions using minimal data. The main reason your code does not work is you are introducing unnecessary variables `first_test` and `second_test`.

This assumes, as stated in your question, you wish to test equality of 2 values from your json given 2 parameter inputs.

**Setup**

```
products = [{'id': 545453435453,
             'title': "product name",
             'fulltitle': "product name"},
            {'id': 123454686786,
             'title': "product name2",
             'fulltitle': "product name3"}]

first_value = input('Name of first value: ')
second_value = input('Name of second value: ')
```

**Solution 1: iteration**

```
for product in products:
    if product[first_value] == product[second_value] :
        print(product['id'])

# Name of first value: title
# Name of second value: fulltitle
# 545453435453
```

**Solution 2: pandas**

This involves the 3rd party library `pandas`, which will be more efficient for repeated calls.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(products)

res = df[df[first_value] == df[second_value]]

# Name of first value: title
# Name of second value: fulltitle
#
#       fulltitle            id         title
# 0  product name  545453435453  product name
```

Comment: I didn't work with pandas before,but I will have a look at it. I looked at your solution, but that way I have to declare the values that I receive from the API in my code right looking at your setup?

Comment: @Solaiman, No, you don't - see update. The setup part remains the same for both solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I can't choose both of your answers as the solution. But upvoted your post :).

Comment: @Solaiman, No problem, you accepted a correct answer.. that's all that matters!